# EOFError when trying to SFTP using paramiko

Tags: python

Can somebody help me to understand what is wrong with the code:

```
import paramiko   
proxy  = paramiko.ProxyCommand('proxycommand')    
client = paramiko.SSHClient()    
client.connect('host', port=22,username='user', password='pwd', sock=proxy)    
ftp = client.open_sftp()    
ftp.get('file1', 'file1')  
ftp.close()  
client.close()
```

I am getting this error for the above code : File "client.py", line 307,   in connect  t.start_client()
    File "/apps/ats/lib/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py",
    line 465, in  start_client  raise e EOFError